Quasi-probability density functions and vanishing expectation
I am interested in the properties of smooth quasi-probability density functions. In two dimensions, these are smooth functions $\rho(x,y):\, \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy the conditions
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\rho(x,y)\,dx\,dy=1\\ &\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\rho(x,y)\,dx\geq0 \\
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\rho(x,y)\,dy\geq0
\end{align}
Given such a function $\rho(x,y)$ and a non-negative function $f(x,y)$ that is also smooth, what conditions does $f(x,y)$ need to satisfy for the following to hold:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\rho(x,y)f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad f(x,y)=0 
\end{equation}
?
When $\rho(x,y)$ is a probability density function, i.e. $\rho(x,y)\geq 0$, this holds for every $f(x,y)$. But can we say something about the general case where $\rho(x,y)$ is a quasi-probability density function but not necessarily a probability density function?

May be it is reasonable to begin with the discrete case of  rectangular matrices $\rho$ with positive sums of rows and columns and $f$ with $f\geq 0$. Assume that $\rho$ is such that trace $\rho f^T=0$ implies $f=0.$ The extreme lines of the cone of $f$  are easy to describe: the only acceptable $\rho$'s seem to be positive.

@LetacGérard I very much like the idea of beginning with the discrete case. The result that if $\rho f^T=0\Rightarrow f=0$ is satisfied for all non-negative $f$ then $\rho$ is positive is interesting. However, I am looking for something slightly different: for general $\rho$, how should we constrain the non-negative $f$ so that the condition $\rho f^T=0\Rightarrow f=0$ holds? For example, if $\rho=\left(\begin{matrix}3&-1\ 2&3\end{matrix}\right)$ and restrict $f$ to be symmetric then the condition is satisfied. I think it may not be a good question, as it may not have a simple general answer.
